# Can the owner of an attached file be set to a queue?

Tags: attachment, contentversion, queue, ownership

My app's users need to be able to view and edit each other's files that they have attached to records. So my idea was to put my users into a Queue and then set the owner to that Queue on upload.

I was able to set the owner to another user by setting the `OwnerId` on `ContentVersion` to the id of the user. But am I able to do this with a Queue or Public Group?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is that your users need to access the attachments that are related with some records. The way this can be achieved is by giving access to the users you want to be able to view and edit the attached file. They should be able to see and edit the record itself.

If you can't give access to the record, for security reasons, consider using profiles and page layouts to remove field access from the interface. Another solution would be to create a custom object, related to the actual record, and give access to those instead of the original record. It is another "jump", but it should work if you can't do it with profiles and sharing rules.